# Using Virtualization (vmware or virtualbox) to setup ipv6 network

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, ipv6, vmware-workstation

So I'm working with a Windows 7 host and have both Virtualbox 4.0.10 and VMware Workstation 7.1.4 installed.  I have been trying to create an IPv6 network that is host only to communicate between the different guests and host.

Anyways, was wondering if anyone has a way to do this, with VMware I haven't been able to find any help and on VirtualBox under the network preferences IPv6 is grayed out for me.

If there is a better solution that someone has for setting up a similar network the main specs are that it must run on my host machine (since I'm limited to my single development machine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to configure a bridged vNIC for your VMs? The VMs will be capable of communicating via IPv6

Comment: Haven't actually tried this implementation, have you used this and does it seem to scale well?

Comment: um... yes of course.

Comment: Did you try it, weijiajun?

Comment: @Mike did this work?